# Angular component can't find jquery file

Tags: jquery, angular

I have followed a tutorial [How to use a Javascript script in Typescript (Angular 5 CLI)](https://siderite.blogspot.com/2018/02/how-to-use-javascript-script-in.html#at572608185) about how to use javascript/jquery in Angular. I have followed the steps but in the component the file can't be found.

I have created a very simple jquery-file named

> jqfilejs.js

and downloaded

> jquery-3.3.1.min.js

.

According to the tutorial

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "assets/js/someJqueryThing.js",...
```

I have added those lines to  angular.cli.json but with my filename

> "assets/js/jqfilejs.js"

and I changed jqueryfileadress to

> "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"

.
Then I created the directories above and added jqfilejs.js in assets/js and added jquery-3.3.1.min.js to node_modules/jquery/dist/.

According to the tutorial I am going to add this line

```
    import('jqfilejs');
    declare function playSound():void;
```

to the typescriptfile. I use it in a component.ts-file. But the import('jqfilejs') declaration get

> [ts] Cannot find module 'jqfilejs'.

message. Do anyone know what I have done wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add assets folder to :

```
"apps": [
{
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist",
  "assets": [
    "assets"     // <<<   
  ],
}]
```

in angular.cli.json .

Comment: Can it have something with the downloaded jQueryfile? I cut it from https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js and saved it as jquery-3.3.1.min.js

Comment: install by this code `npm install jquery@3.3.1` and use `"../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"`

Comment: JQuary installed now, still can't find jqfilejs.js. Do I need to install that one to? I only moved it to assets/js without doing any installation in cmd

Comment: use : `"../src/assets/js/jqfilejs.js"`

Comment: In angular-cli.json? Did not do a difference

Comment: Can there be any problem with how I added the jqfilejs.js to assets/js-folder. I just saved it in the file. Do I need to install that one to?

Answer (score 0):

I used this tutorial instead and use jQuery in Angular where needed instead of downloading library.